# Android animated vector in one file compilation error

Tags: android, animation, vector

I have export a animated vector from https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidIconAnimator/.

the generated file is

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="510dp"
            android:height="510dp"
            android:viewportWidth="510"
            android:viewportHeight="510"
            android:alpha="1">
            <group android:name="group">
                <group android:name="play_circle_outline">
                    <path
                        android:name="path"
                        android:pathData="M 204 369.75 L 357 255 L 204 140.25 L 204 369.75 Z M 255 0 C 114.75 0 0 114.75 0 255 C 0 395.25 114.75 510 255 510 C 395.25 510 510 395.25 510 255 C 510 114.75 395.25 0 255 0 Z M 255 459 C 142.8 459 51 367.2 51 255 C 51 142.8 142.8 51 255 51 C 367.2 51 459 142.8 459 255 C 459 367.2 367.2 459 255 459 Z"
                        android:strokeColor="#000000"/>
                </group>
            </group>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:startOffset="200"
                android:duration="1000"
                android:valueFrom="M 204 369.75 L 357 255 L 204 140.25 L 204 369.75 Z M 255 0 C 114.75 0 0 114.75 0 255 C 0 395.25 114.75 510 255 510 C 395.25 510 510 395.25 510 255 C 510 114.75 395.25 0 255 0 Z M 255 459 C 142.8 459 51 367.2 51 255 C 51 142.8 142.8 51 255 51 C 367.2 51 459 142.8 459 255 C 459 367.2 367.2 459 255 459 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 204 369.75 L 360 180 L 204 369.75 L 150 336.75 Z M 255 0 C 114.75 0 0 114.75 0 255 C 0 395.25 114.75 510 255 510 C 395.25 510 510 395.25 510 255 C 510 114.75 395.25 0 255 0 Z M 255 459 C 142.8 459 51 367.2 51 255 C 51 142.8 142.8 51 255 51 C 367.2 51 459 142.8 459 255 C 459 367.2 367.2 459 255 459 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

But it is giving multiple error when im adding the file in android studio.

first error is :
Element animated-vector doesnt ave required attrbute android:drawable.
Second error in line 4 is :

attribute is missing the android namespace prefix

and online 22 animation attribute should be defined.

Why this errors are occuring ?

i ave seen https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html and here the one part file is almost same.

Answer (score 0):

This is android studio editor bug [Issue 227137](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227137). Btw on android studio 2.3 this files compiles and runs just fine, I tried it with your drawable)

[image]